# Adding a Library to your build and link path in XCode

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-leopard, juce

I am tryingo to build a GUI application using the JUCE framework on MAC OSX. 
I have dowloaded all the API's and got a small hello World program running fine.

However, when I add files to my Xcode project I get compilation errors that say that the Juce library files don`t exist. I would like to know how to get the library API in the build and link path in XCode so that it finds the neccesary files for compilation.

What I would do on Visual Studio going to properties and adding aditional library dependencies, is what I need to do in XCode but I don't know how.
Any help greatly appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but maybe a useful answer in the future....

If you have the "Hello World" up and runnning, it should already be linked to the library. Are you using the introjucer? This should help get everything up and running for you. If you are, you need to add classes etc to the introjucer, as this sets up Xcode / VStudio for you. If not, (Presuming XCode 3 as you are using leopard) goto Xcode > Preferences. Scroll along to source trees, and add the path to the juce folder in there.